# How to use dataset attributes when creating an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset

I've got a piece of code like this:

```
$('<button/>', {
        text: 'Send',
        dataUrl: pageUrl,
        dataTitle: pageTitle,
        class: 'cannedSend'
    }).appendTo('#btnSpan');
}
```

Usually when there is a hyphen in the attribute you can camel case it (marginRight for example) and on the HTML side it shows as margin-right. Nevertheless, for the dataset attributes it simply writes dataurl with no hyphen. Concatenating .attr('data-url', pageUrl).attr('data-title', pageTitle) just looks ugly, and using an object to pass them both in the same .attr() results in the same issue as above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of trying before I asked the question, once I asked it I found the solution.

Simply quote the attribute, like so:

```
$('<button/>', {
    text: 'Send',
    'data-url': pageUrl,
    'data-title': pageTitle,
    class: 'cannedSend'
}).appendTo('#btnSpan');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could either quote the property names like so:

```
$('<button/>', {
        text: 'Send',
        "data-url": pageUrl,
        "data-title": pageTitle,
        class: 'cannedSend'
    }).appendTo('#btnSpan');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xbgnuudb/)

Or use [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$('<button/>', {
        text: 'Send',
        class: 'cannedSend'
    })
    .data({
        url: pageUrl,
        title: pageTitle
    })
    .appendTo('#btnSpan');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjrmwywt/)

Comment: Thanks @RGraham, I found the first solution you proposed a moment after posting the question. Funny how it works some times.